# How to calculate total of all properties within the object in C#?

Tags: c#, object, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

```
public class Calories
{
  public decimal A { get; set; }
  public decimal B { get; set; }
  public decimal C { get; set; }
  public decimal Total { get; set; }
}

var calories = new Calories
{ 
  A = 10, B = 25, C = 31
};

//Currently I am doing this
calories.Total = calories.A + calories.B + calories.C;
```

What is the efficient way to calculate total of all properties in the same object?

Comment: Why not use a `List` or array of calories items and loop through that loop to get the total rather than creating properties?

Comment: Will the class/properties be known or is this just an example of something that you might want to calculate?

Comment: The idea here is how to make the calculation more easy & better performance when it is single object and all properties have same data type. This is for my real code application so no concept of using List!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. You can calculate the sum inside the property getter:

```
public decimal Total { get { return A + B + C } };
```

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't really answer your question, but if you are open to a different design, and you want a class with an undetermined number of values with Total property..

```
class Calories : List<decimal>
{
    public decimal Total { get { return this.Sum(); } }
}
```

Might not be the best way.. depends on the circumstances, but fast and minimal code.

Answer (score 2):

While this is dramatically slower than simply manually adding your decimals together and is somewhat rigid since you're explicitly excluding the Total property by string, the following reflection will total only your Decimal columns without breaking if it encounters a property that is not a decimal.

```
public class Calories
{
    public decimal A { get; set; }
    public decimal B { get; set; }
    public decimal C { get; set; }
    public string TestString { get;set;}

    public decimal Total 
    { 
        get
        {
            return typeof(Calories)
                .GetProperties()
                .Where (x => x.PropertyType == typeof(decimal) 
                    && x.Name != "Total")
                .Sum(p => (decimal)p.GetValue(this));
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that either better class structure or Yuval's answer would be preferable since it properly maintains both strong typing AND performance.  I added this as the "pure reflection" answer for completeness.

Finally, if you wanted to use reflection to dynamically access an unknown number of decimal properties but you wanted to avoid the heavy reflection cost, you could use a library like [FastMember](https://code.google.com/p/fast-member/) to mitigate the performance hit.

```
public class Calories
{
    public decimal A { get; set; }
    public decimal B { get; set; }
    public decimal C { get; set; }
    public string TestString { get;set;}

    public decimal Total 
    { 
        get
        {
            var accessor = FastMember.TypeAccessor.Create(this.GetType());

            return accessor.GetMembers()
                .Where (x => x.Type == typeof(decimal) && x.Name != "Total")
                .Sum(p => (decimal)accessor[this, p.Name]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to sum them when i declare decimal? like nullable property...

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a `List` of `Calories` and inside your class you could have a `Property Total` that call `Sum` on your List

Like so:

```
public class Calories
{
  public List<decimal> Calories;
  public decimal Total{ get { return this.Calories.Sum(); } }

  public Calories()
  {
    this.Calories = new List<decimal>();
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding an item to that internal list would be a bit ugly.. calories.Calories.Add(x)

Comment: Yeah I like your answer :P